# pip hangs when installing package

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm trying to use this jq python module in my Python 3.4 program. I want to parse JSON that I get back from a REST API. I have used jq on the command line and it works great, so I thought it would be a good idea to use this Python binding I found. However, I am having trouble installing the module on my Debian Jessie machine.

Here is the package I want:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq

Here is the output when I run `pip3 install jq`:

```
root@deb:~/Downloads# pip3 -vvv install jq
Collecting jq
  1 location(s) to search for versions of jq:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 351
  Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
  Freshness lifetime from request max-age: 600
  The response is "fresh", returning cached response
  600 > 351
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/49/e3/7e61310ac490f52ea3c58669059d6d374c339b70babc43289ab4e5284f29/jq-0.1.3.tar.gz#md5=17e5ea3b04b44a66e5cd394a3fb0cde2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/6e/a5/b5e87cf3a7fb0e4b13190f2dd10441ddf44df427420ff48e85a2873ee76f/jq-0.1.4.tar.gz#md5=3be49987665648b0232148aa55181bd0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/82/0c/bf3f544f850cef19f4468bea93e4d0aa908e0d8c601609ba1ed561b42c79/jq-0.1.6.tar.gz#md5=5a5fd1d5bbd592a1e987740289c859c9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/a1/e3/00bde129cb6e2bd51cb1f86dadf15c628f077a1881224188d5d4954f6278/jq-0.1.2.tar.gz#md5=8f182b2d92f02d498713d64636cbce9c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/b4/6d/a9e4ce7a3aa3762567530fb6daaaba770710937ac20d425b3b79fbfdff45/jq-0.1.5.tar.gz#md5=5427a8c60668962d279882c3ef467f0c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/07/9bee593118186d049ab6c62117ff55a9a9807970280bb91bc7690b4df295/jq-0.1.1.tar.gz#md5=f71a002f36f111d644bdda46c4f2eb18 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/f9/f8/13737001ce6cd1e628f767cda920efe815e256b4518f7d452c6e495ecc15/jq-0.1.0.tar.gz#md5=72ff8950d769d43ac78ff1c6d31c23a5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/), version: 0.1.0
  Using version 0.1.6 (newest of versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6)
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/packages/82/0c/bf3f544f850cef19f4468bea93e4d0aa908e0d8c601609ba1ed561b42c79/jq-0.1.6.tar.gz" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 20278
  Freshness lifetime from max-age: 31557600
  The response is "fresh", returning cached response
  31557600 > 20278
  Using cached jq-0.1.6.tar.gz
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/82/0c/bf3f544f850cef19f4468bea93e4d0aa908e0d8c601609ba1ed561b42c79/jq-0.1.6.tar.gz#md5=5a5fd1d5bbd592a1e987740289c859c9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/jq/)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-rppc1fh7/jq/setup.py) egg_info for package jq
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/jq.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-build-rppc1fh7/jq has version 0.1.6, which satisfies requirement jq from https://pypi.python.org/packages/82/0c/bf3f544f850cef19f4468bea93e4d0aa908e0d8c601609ba1ed561b42c79/jq-0.1.6.tar.gz#md5=5a5fd1d5bbd592a1e987740289c859c9
Building wheels for collected packages: jq
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for jq ...   Destination directory: /tmp/tmp5lqhtjtmpip-wheel-
  Running command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-rppc1fh7/jq/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp5lqhtjtmpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Executing: ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --prefix=/tmp/pip-build-rppc1fh7/jq/onig-install-5.9.6
```

When it reaches that last line about installing Oniguruma, it freezes for over 10 minutes.

I don't see anything relevant in `top`:

```
top - 15:37:27 up 1 day,  6:54,  3 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.03, 0.05
Tasks: 136 total,   1 running, 135 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.4 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1014456 total,   919136 used,    95320 free,    60568 buffers
KiB Swap:  2075644 total,        0 used,  2075644 free.   462572 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
25561 root      20   0   23636   2984   2496 R   0.7  0.3   0:00.23 top
  990 mysql     20   0  558176 188352  10576 S   0.3 18.6   2:28.97 mysqld
    1 root      20   0   28704   4932   3092 S   0.0  0.5   0:03.86 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:00.32 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:08.01 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.98 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.08 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:15.96 ksoftirqd/1
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
   16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.01 watchdog/2
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.39 migration/2
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   2:33.87 ksoftirqd/2
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   2:09.74 kworker/2:0
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H
   21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.78 watchdog/3
   22 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.36 migration/3
   23 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   3:06.01 ksoftirqd/3
   25 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H
   26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
   27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
```

Comment: did you check in another shell, if it's doing something, e.g. running `top`?

Comment: @tuergeist  I don't see anything relevant in top. I posted top output in my post.

Comment: tried it my own, it shall not block there... Hmm.  Are u running on a native debian?

Comment: @tuergeist I am running Debian Jessie. It also hangs when I try to install pyjq. It might be waiting for input on stdin. I am going to take a closer look at the oniguruma files since that is where it hangs.

Comment: pstree and strace might be useful to figure out what that process is doing